# AJAX call in jQuery, what defines a "json" as parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I found this line of code. This AJAX call's last parameter is a string, "json".

What does it stand for?

```
$.get(theUrl, function(e) {
    make(e);
  }, "json")
```

Comment: Please read the docs: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: see the last example in https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This parameter indicates the expected return type. The possible values are `xml`, `json`, `script`, or `html`. When you specify the expected return type, jQUery will automatically parse the response form the server and provide to the success callback an already processed variable.

If you omit this parameter then jQuery will use the `Content-Type` response header that is sent from the server to determine how to process the response. For example if the server sends `Content-Type: application/json` then jQuery will automatically parse the response into a javascript object that will be passed to the success callback.

Usually if the server side script that you are calling is properly written and respects web standards by specifying the correct Content-Type response header you don't need to be explicitly setting this parameter in your AJAX call:

```
$.get(theUrl, function(e) {
    // If the server set the Content-Type header to application/json
    // then the "e" variable passed to this function will already be
    // a parsed javascript object
    make(e);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It means that [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) will return data type `json`

dataType: (example: xml, json, script, or html)

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback).

---

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See [json.org](http://json.org/) for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

Answer (score 0):

That's any data you want to be passed to the server which needs to be in object notation like so:

```
{
   param1: "data1",
   param2: "data2"
}
```

these will basically become the get parameters at the end of the request url like so:

http://example-site.com/request-link?param1=data1&param2=data2

Answer (score 0):

it's a returned data type: see the [last paragraph](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)